# Pass record parameter without declaring it first as a variable

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

If I am trying to call a procedure which has a record type (not object) as a parameter, is it possible to somehow pass details of that parameter "inline" without having to declare a variable of that type first?

eg assume I have this simple record type:

```
type TMyRecord = record
  AString: string;
  AnInt: Integer;
end;
```

and this procedure declaration:

```
procedure MyProcedure(Rec: TMyRecord);
```

If I want to call MyProcedure do I have to declare a variable of type TMyRecord or can I do something like:

```
MyProcedure(TMyRecord("Test", 10));
```

That doesn't work (XE2) (get a compiler error about it expecting a ")").

So, can I do something like that?  Or not possible.

Thanks

Comment: A war is going on below. I think that the ideal answer would be "There is no syntax to create an arbitrary record instance 'inline', but *for any given record*, you can achieve essentially the same level of convenience by [Brian's answer follows]"

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It is possible using the `advanced record` structure.

For more information about `advanced records`, see the [Records (advanced) section](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Structured_Types) in Delphi help.

This is a small prototype to see how it works in your case to preinitialize a record in a function/procedure call :

```
Type
  TRecord = record
   AString : String;
   AnInt : Integer;
   Constructor Create( Const s : String; i : Integer);
  end;

constructor TRecord.Create(const s: String; i: Integer);
begin
  AString := s;
  AnInt := i;
end;

procedure DoSomething( theRec : TRecord);
begin
  WriteLn(theRec.AString, ' ',theRec.AnInt);
end;

begin
  DoSomeThing( TRecord.Create('S',1));
  ReadLn;
end.
```

Looking at the Delphi RTL, see the definitions of the record types `TPoint` and `TRect` in unit `system.types` (XE2).
They define some overloaded `Create` constructors, which are used in lots of places to preinitialize the record structures in function/procedure calls.

Comment: @KenWhite: A single function so you can avoid declaring a var everywhere you just want to pass a couple of values, does not seem like "lots of code" to me. That the type is declared elsewhere is moot (as long as it is not in a library).

Comment: I am not going to participate in the 'war' going on here, but as far as the distinction between this approach and Brian's goes, I am still not sure which one I prefer...

Comment: For historical reasons, it's beneficial to offer workaround solutions.

Comment: @Andreas - Not that it should be a reason of preference, but one difference is that the standalone function can be inlined.

Comment: @Sertac, there's no technical reason that the compiler couldn't inline the constructor version, too. I'd like to think that the two versions compile down to very similar machine code. If Delphi doesn't inline constructor calls, that seems like a limitation of the current compiler, not something inherent to record constructors.

Answer (score 19):

The question you are asking relates to code readability and there is a solution that avoids having to create a variable. The VCL uses this solution with the records `TPoint` and `TRect`.

Consider the definition of `TPoint`:

```
type
  TPoint = record
    X,Y integer
  end;
```

To pass a `TPoint` to a procedure you might do:

```
var
  MyPoint : TPoint;

begin
  MyPoint.X := 5;
  MyPoint.Y := 7;
  DoSomething( MyPoint );
end;
```

This is fine but takes 3 lines when one is also possible using the factory function `Point`:

```
begin
  DoSomething( Point(5,7) );
end;
```

In Delphi, a function has been declared as follows:

```
function Point( X, Y : integer ) : TPoint;
begin
  Result.X := X;
  Result.Y := Y;
end;
```

You can then call this function 'inline' to create the record 'on the fly' to to quickly
You will see the same has been provided for `TRect` etc. I often put such a factory function together with the record declaration as follows, even if I don't plan to use them yet:

```
type
  TMyRecord = record
    A : integer;
    B : string;
  end;

function MyRecord( A : integer; const B : string ) : TMyRecord;
begin
  Result.A := A;
  Result.B := B;
end;
```

Use of this technique can improved the readability of code and also ensures that you don't accidently omit setting a record element.

Comment: I think it _does_ answer the question ("So, can I do something like that?" - Brian Frost supplies a way to do something like that :))

Comment: @KenWhite: A single function `MyRect` so you can avoid declaring a var everywhere you just want to pass a couple of values, does not seem like "lots of code" to me. That the type is declared elsewhere is completely moot in this solution.

Comment: @KenWhite: If we only ever answered the exact question asked, SO would be a lot less helpful than it is. Maybe both Brian and LU RD should have prefaced their answers with "No it can't be done, but here is a workaround", but to my view that is implied in their answering with something other than a short Yes/No.

Comment: @KenWhite Yes it happens. No worries there :-) And if the answers given by Brian and LU RD had not been Delphi specific I would have agreed with you. But they were Delphi specific. In my view reading the intention as well as the literal words of a question is important.

Comment: @KenWhite: If you look in the VCL source (and other well-established libraries) you see the Point(X,Y) factory solution all over the place and reason is that if you went to the trouble of declaring a record in the first place, it's probably quite an important structure to you with significant scope - hence it's worth adding a factory function if you plan to initialise it inline.

Comment: @Brian Have you seen the definition of `TPoint` in the latest Delphi source? Now has a constructor so that you can use `TPoint.Create` as an alternative. Also has operator overloading for equality and add/subtract operators.

Answer (score 6):

Just having fun with John Easley's idea:

```
type TRec = record
  X: string;
  Y: Integer;
end;

procedure TestRec(const Rec: array of const);
var
  R: TRec;

begin
  R.X:= string(Rec[0].VUnicodeString);
  R.Y:= Rec[1].VInteger;
  ShowMessage(R.X + IntToStr(R.Y));
end;

procedure TForm1.Button7Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TestRec(['Test', 22]);
end;
```

It is possible to pass record fields as `array of const` parameters and assign these parameters to local record variable.

Comment: -1. It's unnecessarily complex. Declare the function with two parameters, one for each field. Give them specific types. Remove the brackets from the call site.

Comment: @RobKennedy - Your proposals are dull. Programming should be fun. :)

Answer (score 2):

It would be nice! But, no.

If passing things inline is really your objective, then perhaps Open Array Parameters would suit you.

```
Procedure MyProcedure(const Vars: Array of Variant);
begin
  ShowMessage(VarToStr(Vars[0])+'  '+VarToStr(Vars[1]));
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
   MyProcedure(['Test', 12]);
end;
```

You could also pass an Array of Const, which is basically an array of TVarRec which is a variant record that also includes type information as VType.  This is fun stuff..

An excellent article can be found on Rudy's Delphi Corner here:
[Rudy's Delphi Corner, Open Array Parameters](http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-openarr.html)

Comment: -1. I see no reason to do it this way. If you're not going to pass the whole record, it would be much better to simply declare two distinct typed parameters. Then the compiler can tell you whether you have everything, instead of the function having to check it at run time.

Comment: Wow, a -1 for offering a way to pass a record without creating a local var? I don't see how my answer wasn't applied to the question.. I don't see up voting, but down vote?  again, wow.

Comment: If it hadn't applied to the question, I'd have flagged it. Your answer applies to the question, but it's a lousy answer because it takes a task that can easily be strongly typed and makes it weakly typed and syntactically odd.